# Facebook Sdk share only one post

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I use Facebook SDK in android to post on Facebook.

login works fine but when try to post on Facebook I can share one post only.

and I does not catch any error so how to solve it please.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "user_photos, publish_checkins, publish_actions, publish_stream" };
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

Login:

```
facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

and for post:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
        try {
            facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")
                    || response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            } else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware about the library called Simple Facebook @https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook , If you are not, try it. and u gonna say WOW! sure... because that library will help you to make your Facebook Integration much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Prevent redundant posts Facebook remove second one